# Needing to encrypt plain sight information

Tags: encryption

Okay here are my requirements.

I need a solution that can do the following.

Lets say I have an encrypted piece of text with the value "20".

and I have UserA and UserB

I give UserA the Keys (/5 and /2), meaning divide by 5 and divide by 2.
I give UserB the Key (/10 and /1) meaning divide by 10 and divide by 1.

using both operations, both UserA and UserB can arrive at the same result the un-encrypted text of "2".

The first operation could be their "SessionID, the second could be a corresponding key for the Session".  Two different users, using two different "Keys" can decrypt the ciphertext using two different but equal operations.

Is there something similar in cryptography where you can provide different keys or functions and arrive at the same result and is cryptographically secure.

Comment: Use TLS + server-side user authentication.

Comment: TLS doesn't encrypt the plain in sight content, it encrypts it over the wire. The decryption needs to occur on the client side. i.e within a javascript function in a browser. I can use a server to provide a combination values that can be used in decryption but the constraint is that the page must be pre-encrypted and in plain sight. i.e publicly browse able.

Comment: I guess one way of looking at this problem would be if there is a file that is encrypted once but can be decrypted using many different unique keys
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597188/encryption-with-multiple-different-keys

Comment: Encrypt content with a randomly generated key. Encrypt this key for each user with a user-specific key.

Comment: I cannot "Encrypt this key for each user", it needs to be encrypted once, in plain sight.  multiple keys to decrypt the one file.

Comment: But the problem *doesn't make sense* if the resulting decrypted page is the same for all users, just give them all the same key. Unless the keys are used somewhere else, it does not make any difference.

Comment: @Andrew Also, dchest didn't say "encrypt the data", he said "encrypt the key" - there is a big difference, the data is still only encrypted once ;)

Comment: @Andrew User1 can give away decrypted plaintext without revealing any keys anyway. Perhaps, you can tell us what kind of problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

The answer in the comments from dchest is probably the most standard. Encrypt the page with a single, random key. Then encrypt that key for each user using the shared secret that you hold with that user.

It is unclear whether this meets your needs as it is unclear exactly what your needs are.

With that in mind, a fairly advanced way you could get the functionality you require is with [Ciphertext-Policy Attribute Based Encryption](http://eprint.iacr.org/2008/290.pdf). It is very complex and would require a lot to describe in this answer (and I don't even know if it meets your needs as they seem to not be fully defined at this point).